# Highcharts - display label on yAxis

Tags: highcharts

I have column created from array

```
[
  {name: 'Item 1', data: [123]},
  {name: 'Item 2', data: [234]},
  {name: 'Item 3', data: [456]},
 ....
]
```

Bar will look like this

http://prntscr.com/4evdd5

I need to remove this axis numbers and on same place to display item name ('Item 1', 'Item 2', ...) near each slice.

Also, I need this name to be right from chart.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [Renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.text) to add custom text.